# How to start with zero counter verilog

Tags: verilog, bit-shift

I'm implementing a repeating bit shifter for a 16 bit number. To do this, I have a bit counter that counts how many times I've shifted and resets when I reach 4'b1111. Then I have an assign statement that feeds the MSB to an output. However, the logic makes it so that the output skips the first MSB every time. **What is the most succinct way to include the first MSB, before any shifting has occurred?**

CODE

```
module DAC_Control(
  input [15:0]data_in,
  input clk,
  input rst,
  output data_out,
  output reg cs,
  output reg enable
  );

//bit counter
  reg [3:0] bit_counter;

//to help with shifting
  reg [15:0] shifter;

  always @(data_in)
    shifter <= data_in;

//shifter
  always @(posedge (clk)) begin
    if (rst) begin
      bit_counter <= 4'b0;
      enable <= 1'b0;
      cs <= 1'b1;
      end
    else if (bit_counter == 4'b1111) begin
      bit_counter <= 4'b0;
      enable <= 1'b1;
      cs <= 1'b1;
    end
    else begin //this is the problem area
      bit_counter <= bit_counter + 1'b1;
      enable <= 1'b0;
      cs <= 1'b0;
      shifter <= shifter << 1;

    end
  end

  assign data_out = shifter[15];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly it would be better to have a trigger to capture the data_in. If not then **in simulation** ,if the data_in changes in between the shifting it will update the shifter and cause the expected output to change. It would be preferable to capture the data_in based on a qualifying event ( e.g. counter_enable in the example below) . **Synthesis** will produce an error as `shifter` has two drivers . One the continuous assignment  `shifter <= data_in;` and other the shifting logic  `shifter <= shifter << 1;`

Updated sample code should serialize the data.

```
module DAC_Control(
  input [15:0]data_in,
  input  counter_enable,
  input clk,
  input rst,
  output data_out,
  output reg cs,
  output reg enable
  );

//bit counter
  reg [3:0] bit_counter;

//to help with shifting
  reg [15:0] shifter;

//shifter
  always @(posedge (clk)) begin
    if (rst) begin
      bit_counter <= 4'b0;
      shifter <= 0;
      end
    else if (counter_enable == 1) begin
        shifter <= data_in;
        bit_counter <= 4'b0;
    end
    else begin
      shifter <= shifter << 1; // shifting 
      bit_counter <= bit_counter + 1'b1; // counter 
    end
  end

  always @(posedge (clk)) begin
    if (rst) begin
      enable <= 1'b0;
      cs <= 1'b1;
      end
    else if (bit_counter == 4'b1111) begin
      enable <= 1'b1;
      cs <= 1'b1;
    end
    else begin 
      enable <= 1'b0; // generate enable signals 
      cs <= 1'b0;
    end
  end

  assign data_out = shifter[15];

endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't clarify that data_in only changes when the enable pulse is sent out, so that's not the issue. But your code should fix the problem of it starting on the 2nd MSB rather than the 1st. However, you say your code gives an error for synthesis? How might one get around that?

Comment: the original code has synthesis error , in the sample above as the shifter is assigned in one one location things should be good.

Comment: it means  the enable can then be used internally to latch data

Comment: ohh, because its assigned in two different always blocks, that causes the problem?

Comment: Yes , one is a continuous assignment => combo logic and other implies a flip flop . the synthesizer  cannot implement both and hence errors out.